# Смена рабочего окружения в Ubuntu 12.04 внутри XRDP

Tags: администрирование, ubuntu

Установил на ПК с ubuntu программу XRDP (ubuntu а альтернативный рабочий стол LXDE). С подключением проблем нет. Всё нормально. Есть одно НО:после ввода логин\пароля xrdp загружает оболочку юнити, что создаёт большие зависания на компьютере с виндой. Я подправил параметры подключения в самой винде, понизив качество отображения, но тем не менее картинка сильно тормозит. Можно как то указать, что бы xrdp загружал не юнити а LXDE?PS учётная запись, по которой происходит подключение по удалённке на самом пк заходит под LXDE.

Comment: А есть файлик ~/.xinitrc ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблему редактированием файла:/etc/xrdp/startwm.sh

Пример:

```
#!/bin/shif [ -r /etc/default/locale ]; then  . /etc/default/locale  export LANG LANGUAGEfips -Af >/tmp/xrdp.txtstartlxde#. /etc/X11/Xsession
```